# Удаление из массива имея массив удаляемых элементов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Задача удалить из массива данных другой массив имеющихся данных.У меня есть исходный массив, так же у меня есть массив элемнтов которые надо удалить
Например из массива [1,2,3,4,5,6] нужно удалить [2,1,3]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
let arr2 = [2,1,3];
let difference = arr1.filter(x => !arr2.includes(x));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score -1):

Для лучшей производительности можно использовать `Set`:

```js
const oldArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
const toDelete = new Set([2,1,3]);
const newArray = oldArray.filter(x => !toDelete.has(x));
console.log(newArray);
```